# How can I set the default calling application on AndroidTV?

Tags: android, actions-on-google, android-tv

I'm trying to provide Actions using the Google Assistant, one of the actions is to allow the user to start a call from the voice assistant.

As the Android TV ecosystem provides a stub ITelecomService, there seems to be no real way to set the default CALL/DIAL application, and therefore it cannot be recognized as a valid application to handle a call scenario.

I really hope I'm dead wrong, anyone that can provide **assistance** in this issue